# Why is this datum not an example of the avro schema in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, avro

I'm having some trouble decoding an Avro message from Kafka in Python using kafka-python. To boil it down, I'm focusing on just decoding the message using the avro package. I have written a test with the schema and example from the official avro docs: https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedpython.html.

[repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SpiffyRowdyScience#main.py)

```
from avro.io import DatumWriter, DatumReader, BinaryEncoder, BinaryDecoder
import avro.schema
from io import BytesIO

schema = avro.schema.parse("""
    {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "User",
        "namespace": "example.avro",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "favorite_number",
                "type": [
                    "int",
                    "null"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "favorite_color",
                "type": [
                    "string",
                    "null"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
""")

wb = BytesIO()
encoder = BinaryEncoder(wb)
writer = DatumWriter(schema)
writer.write('{"name":"Alyssa","favorite_number":256,"favorite_color":"blue"}', encoder)

rb = BytesIO(wb.getvalue())
decoder = BinaryDecoder(rb)
reader = DatumReader(schema)
msg = reader.read(decoder)

print(msg)
```

I'm receiving an error that `the datum {"name":"Alyssa","favorite_number":256,"favorite_color":"blue"} is not an example of the schema`. What am I doing wrong given that this schema and datum come straight from the official Avro docs for Python?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 36, in <module>
    writer.write('{"name":"Alyssa","favorite_number":256,"favorite_color":"blue"}', encoder)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/avro/io.py", line 979, in write
    raise AvroTypeException(self.writers_schema, datum)
avro.io.AvroTypeException: The datum {"name":"Alyssa","favorite_number":256,"favorite_color":"blue"} is not an example of the schema {
  "type": "record",
  "name": "User",
  "namespace": "example.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "type": "string",
      "name": "name"
    },
    {
      "type": [
        "int",
        "null"
      ],
      "name": "favorite_number"
    },
    {
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ],
      "name": "favorite_color"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You currently have

```
writer.write('{"name":"Alyssa","favorite_number":256,"favorite_color":"blue"}', encoder)
```

So the datum you are providing is a string. If you change it to a dictionary like this:

```
writer.write({"name":"Alyssa","favorite_number":256,"favorite_color":"blue"}, encoder)
```

Then it works.